# Robocopy to mappled SharePoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I mapped a SharePoint online document library(Y:) and was planning to use robocopy to synchronize a local directly to the library. The problem that I am enountering is that it always views the source(local) files as newer. I used /XO, /FFT, and /M and it still lists all source files as new and remote files as extra. If I actually attempt to copy it copies all of the files.

```
robocopy "S:\Job Descriptions" "Y:" /L /XO /FFT
```

The conflicting files are the same size and have the same name while the local files are older. For example the modified date of the old file is 7/8/2016 and the new file 5/19/2019.

Any suggestions that could explain why robocopy is reporting this? Should I just use powershell instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync the library with OneDrive instead.

Comment: I wanted to avoid adding another layer to this but it appears that mapped sharepoint folders break robocopy. I will have to robo from the shared drive to the one drive sync folder.